# Field Repository in Controller required a bean of type Repository that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

First post here.
I am learning spring boot and I've been stuck with trying to get my spring boot application to run for a while.
I assume something with my repository is wrong since when I add the line to my controller class

```
@Autowired
private StoreCardRepository storeCardRepository;
```

I get the following error:

```
2023-05-09T23:39:44.036-07:00  INFO 433094 --- [           main] example.storecard.StoreCardApplication   : Starting StoreCardApplication using Java 18.0.2.1 with PID 433094 (/media/ryuga/656464b7-2c1e-4da4-8da9-54f5442a88fe/ryuga/IdeaProjects/storecard/target/classes started by ryuga in /media/ryuga/656464b7-2c1e-4da4-8da9-54f5442a88fe/ryuga/IdeaProjects/storecard)
2023-05-09T23:39:44.037-07:00  INFO 433094 --- [           main] example.storecard.StoreCardApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-09T23:39:44.371-07:00  INFO 433094 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-05-09T23:39:44.376-07:00  INFO 433094 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-09T23:39:44.376-07:00  INFO 433094 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-05-09T23:39:44.411-07:00  INFO 433094 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-09T23:39:44.412-07:00  INFO 433094 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 356 ms
2023-05-09T23:39:44.435-07:00  WARN 433094 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storeCardController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storeCardRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'example.storecard.StoreCardRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2023-05-09T23:39:44.436-07:00  INFO 433094 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-05-09T23:39:44.443-07:00  INFO 433094 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-09T23:39:44.450-07:00 ERROR 433094 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field storeCardRepository in example.storecard.StoreCardController required a bean of type 'example.storecard.StoreCardRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'example.storecard.StoreCardRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my project structure
[Showing where files are at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s45Oi.png)

And here is the code for each of the files in example.storecard:

StoreCard.java

```
package example.storecard;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public record StoreCard(@Id Long id, Double amount) {
}
```

StoreCardApplication.java

```
package example.storecard;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StoreCardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StoreCardApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

StoreCardController.java

```
package example.storecard;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/storecards")
public class StoreCardController {

    @Autowired
    private StoreCardRepository storeCardRepository;


    @GetMapping("/{requestedId}")
    public ResponseEntity<StoreCard> findById(@PathVariable Long requestedId){
        Optional<StoreCard> storeCard = storeCardRepository.findById(requestedId);
        if(storeCard.isPresent()){
            return ResponseEntity.ok(storeCard.get());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();


    }

}
```

StoreCardRepository.java

```
package example.storecard;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StoreCardRepository extends CrudRepository<StoreCard, Long> {
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>storecard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>StoreCard</name>
    <description>StoreCard service for woodland water store</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysql/mysql-connector-j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Reading through the output I noticed 2 things

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'storeCardController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'storeCardRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'example.storecard.StoreCardRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

and

```
Field storeCardRepository in example.storecard.StoreCardController required a bean of type 'example.storecard.StoreCardRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'example.storecard.StoreCardRepository' in your configuration.
```

I can guess that this is saying that something is wrong with my repository class and spring boot not being able to make a bean for it for some reason. But since that is the extent of my knowledge with spring boot all I can do is google and see if there is another post out there that might solve my issue but I've found nothing so far after trying many possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pom.xml file remove this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Add following instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Change the repository interface to extend JpaRepository like this:

```
public interface StoreCardRepository extends JpaRepository<StoreCard, Long> {
}
```

The entity class can't be a Java record. It should be a Java bean (POJO) with mandatory getters, setters and no-args constructor. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class StoreCard {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private BigDecimal amount;
}
```

Please note: the annotations for getters and setters etc come from Lombok. Very helpful plugin. Otherwise you will need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing the jpa dependency which contains the autoconfigure for your datasource

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```